# Invoke a templated member from a c-function using void pointer

Tags: c++, c, templates, void-pointers

My c++ code has to work with an underlying c-library. I have a c++ object that looks somewhat like this:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
public:
  explicit MyClass(int x)
  : mVar(x)
  {
  }

private:
  int mVar;
};
```

Later in my c++ code I do the following:

```
  auto p = new MyClass<int>(10);

  call_c_lib_function((void*) p);
```

The c function saves the pointer 'p' in a larger c-structure. Later when the large
c object is getting destroyed, it invokes the delete handler.

```
void
c_delete_handler(void* data)
{
  // data is holding the pointer value 'p' from above.
}
```

Since the object is getting destroyed, I need to free the object that allocated.
Per the c++ spec, 'delete void_ptr' is undefined since it doesn't know how to
invoke the appropriate destructor. How do I invoke delete on the appropriate
template object?

One solution I could think of was to create a wrapper structure around my MyClass pointer.

```
struct Wrapper {
  enum template_type {
    template_int,
    template_double,
    template_string,
    ...
  };

  int template_type;
  void* obj_ptr;
};
```

before callign the call_c_lib_function, I'd do the following:

```
  auto p = new MyClass<int>(10);
  auto w = new Wrapper()
  w.template_type = Wrapper::template_int;
  w.obj_ptr = (void*) p;

  call_c_lib_function((void) w);
```

and now in the delete handler, I can do the following:

```
void
c_delete_handler(void* data)
{
  Wrapper* w = (Wrapper*) data;

  switch (w->template_type) {
    case Wrapper::template_int:
      delete (MyClass<int>*) w->obj_ptr;
      break;

    case Wrapper::template_double:
      delete (MyClass<double>*) w->obj_ptr;
      break;
    ...
  }
}
```

Is this a correct approach? is there a better alternative?
Would appreciate any inputs. Thanks.

Comment: This is more a C++ question than a C one.  Tags edited.

Comment: Just allocate it with a smart pointer (`shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr` etc.) and let it collect itself later. `void*` isn't used all that much in C++. Otherwise, you'll have to keep track of the type of the pointee and cast it before you delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `Wrapper`, use a base class, if that's an option.

```
class MyBase
{
   public:
      virtual ~MyBase() {};
};

template <typename T>
class MyClass : public MyBase
{
   public:
     explicit MyClass(int x) : mVar(x) {}

   private:
     int mVar;
};
```

and then

```
void c_delete_handler(void* data)
{
  Base* basePtr = reinterpret_cast<Base*>(data);
  delete basePtr;
}
```

This approach obviates the need for keeping track of whether `MyClass` was instantiated using `int`, `double`, `std::string`, or ....

Comment: Will that call the correct destructor for derived types? (Not saying it won't - I'm honestly not sure.)

Comment: @3Dave,  Yes, it will. That's what `virtual` destructors are for.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.